# Receiving Incorrect Serial Data on Arduino

Tags: android, serialization, arduino-uno

I need to grab my x/y coordinates from the tablet, do some math to them then prefix each with a letter (Z in the code below) before sending them over a serial link.  Everything works except for the sending and receiving of them over the serial link.
The toast in my example tells me that WRP is being correctly calculated, Z10.0 for example.  But on my receive side serial monitor I get 50 (linefeed) 46.  The 50 is stable, the 46 changes, but not consistently, and not equal to A.

If I try “sendData("S");”  I correctly receive an S on my serial monitor.

For simplicity’s sake I have boiled down the problem to the following;

On the transmit side:

```
btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                A=A+1;
                String WRP = (Double.toString(A));
                WRP = "Z"+ WRP;
                sendData(WRP);
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        WRP, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                msg.show();
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendData("S");
            }
        });
```

AND

```
 private void sendData(String message) {
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

    Log.d(TAG, "...Sending data: " + message + "...");

    try {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
        if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
            msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 37 in the java code";
        msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

        errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
    }
}
```

On the Receive side:

```
    void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available())
    dataFromBT = mySerial.read();
    Serial.println(mySerial.read());
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Don

Comment: You're writing a string but you're reading a single byte, and then you're passing that to `println()`, which will append a line terminator.  I don't see any reason why anything should be equal to 'A'.

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you need to fix yet.